# Unable to insert everything in database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

While trying to insert new fetched data into Laravel, I am unable to insert 2 fields i.e. type and provider into the database.

Here is my code:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $userData->name,
    'username' => $userData->name,
    'email' => $userData->email,
    'password' => 'asdffdas',
    'type' => 'standard',
    'provider' => $userData->id,
    'active' => 1
  ]);
```

If I echo `$userData->id`, I manage to receive a valid integer, however on after insertion, the type is always the first `enum` while provider is always 0.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: may be you want to echo `$user->id`, not `$userData->id`?

Comment: is the provider a `tinyint` by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that the fields are in the $fillable = []; parameter of your model.

**Mass Assignment**

When creating a new model, you pass an array of attributes to the model constructor. These attributes are then assigned to the model via mass-assignment. This is convenient; however, can be a serious security concern when blindly passing user input into a model. If user input is blindly passed into a model, the user is free to modify any and all of the model's attributes. For this reason, all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

```
To get started, set the fillable or guarded properties on your model.

Defining Fillable Attributes On A Model

The fillable property specifies which attributes should be mass-assignable. This can be set at the class or instance level.

class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

}
```